# Longtable with vertical multirows- pagebreaking/positioning

Tags: page-breaking, multirow

I recently redid my diabetes logbook to have a separate column w/ a multirow for date, instead of an extra row, which wastes horizon real estate. With the new setup, however, I'm unsure of how to get page-terminal days to no appear pagebroken without multiple pagebreaks and wasted vertical space.

I *assume* one-page scroll-type documents don't exist, so I'm looking for any solution. Here's what I'm using-

```
\documentclass{article}[9pt]
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,longtable,multirow,multicol,rotating,booktabs}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.25cm, right=1.25cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\selectcolormodel{gray}\rowcolors{2}{white}{yellow}
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{l l| l l l l l | p{11cm}}

\rowcolor{white}\caption{title}\\
%
\rowcolor{white}\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Time} & BG & Ins. & CHO & Pro & Fat & Remarks \\ \hline\endfirsthead
%
\rowcolor{white}\caption{\emph{cont.}}\\ 
\rowcolor{white}\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Time} & BG & Ins. & CHO & Pro & Fat & Remarks \\ \hline\endhead
\hline\endfoot
%%% Copy-paste as many date as necessary to see issue
    \cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{yellow}\rotatebox{90}{08.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{white}\rotatebox{90}{09.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
%%% 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Actual example.]

Comment: if i understood you correctly, you need after each 6th `\multirow` cell insert `\newpage`.

Comment: @Zarko That's the obvious 'solution', however, I don't want extra vertical space. Placing the date on the upper and/or lower part of a divided day works only if there are 3 or more rows.

Comment: see my answer below. if you not liked, i will delete it. what you looking for is (almost) impossible to achieve

Comment: the optional argument here is doing nothing `\documentclass{article}[9pt]`  that argument should be a `[1994/07/01]` but latex just ignores it is not of that form.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I commented to copy-past the given two days enough times to make it break up. In regards to the optional argument- thanks.

Comment: yes sorry I realized that later (and deleted my comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after over days of fiddling, I created my own solution to the problem, it  works, at least. Making it simpler yielded less complexity and more simply fixable errors.

**EDITS**-  1) Currently, all `\mutlirow`s are properly aligned; `\ddate` is called for `mrow>2`, whereby you get a 2-digit year if `mrow>4`. 2) If less than 3 rows of a day appear on top of page the next date was misaligned, due to mistake, reworked some redundancies in macros. 3) I made a .sty with all the commands and counters; yet again simplified to but one command- `\QQQ`, downside being if one day gets linebroken, the one on the next page won't be the same color, date'll appear so it's more of an aesthetic nuisance. 4) Vertical alignment of days with short/long date format, and minor changes. 5) Everything is aligned *always*, extra lines of text in the `m` Remarks column get counted depending on whether or not it's the last row of resp. date, always `\myc` number of rows per page; there is only two commands to use `\QQQ` and `\ddate`- when the next entry is after 23:59, this is so the args that get put into a `.dat` file have the correct time *and* date. No day, month, year stepping required either.

```
\documentclass{article}
%========================PACKAGES%========================
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{
    lmodern,
    microtype,
    % showframe,
    etoolbox,
    calc,
    xstring,
    rotating,
    booktabs,
    array,
    longtable,
    multicol,
    multirow,
    newfile,
    pgf
    }
\usepackage[top=0.5cm, bottom=0.8cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font={rm,small}, labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{bookmark}
%========================COLOR OPTIONS%========================
    \definecolor{oddRowColor}{cmyk}{0.1,0.5,0.1,0.91}% 
    \definecolor{evenRowColor}{cmyk}{0.3,0.5,0.1,0.97}% 
    \colorlet{evenRowTextColor}{-evenRowColor}% 
    \colorlet{oddRowTextColor}{-oddRowColor}%
    \definecolor{pageBG}{HSB}{47,22,26}%
    % TABLE RULES, HEADERS, FOOTERS COLOR
    \definecolor{tc0}{cmyk}{.40,0,0,.15}% 
    % CAPTION COLOR
    \DeclareCaptionFont{cc}{\color{green!70}}%
    \captionsetup{font+={cc}}%
    \AtBeginDocument{
        \pagecolor{pageBG}%
        \color{tc0}%
        \rowcolors{2}{oddRowColor}{evenRowColor}%
        }%
%========================COUNTERS%========================
    \newbool{rcc}
    \newbool{rc}
    % HYPERREF TO LABEL LONGTABLE ROWS
    \newcounter{ltrow}
    % MULTIROW LENGTH AND PAGE ROW #
    \newcounter{mrow}
    \newcounter{row}
    % DATE COUNTERS
    \newcounter{year}
    \newcounter{month}[year]
    \newcounter{day}[month]
%========================COMMANDS%========================
    \newcommand*{\ddate}{% calls date, then increments
        \small%
        \ifbool{rcc}% DATE TEXT COLOR
            {\color{oddRowTextColor}\global\boolfalse{rcc}}%
            {\color{evenRowTextColor}\global\booltrue{rcc}}%
        \ifnumcomp{\value{mrow}}{>}{2}% ROOM FOR DATE?
            {% DATE FORM
                \ifnumcomp{\value{mrow}}{>}{4}% 
                    {\multirow{-\value{mrow}}{*}}%
                    {\multirow{-\value{mrow}}{*}}%
                {\rotatebox{90}{% for m column
                    \ifnumcomp{\value{day}}{<}{10}% IF SINGLE DIGIT DAY
                        {0\theday.}%
                        {\theday.}%
                    \ifnumcomp{\value{month}}{<}{10}% IF SINGLE DIGIT MONTH
                        {0\themonth.}%
                        {\themonth.}%
                    \ifnumcomp{\value{mrow}}{>}{4}% ROOM FOR YEAR?
                        {\StrRight{\theyear}{2}}%
                        {}%
                    }%
                }%
            }%
            {}%
        \ifnum 
            \value{day} = 31%
            \ifnum \value{month} = 12%
                \stepcounter{year}% YEAR STEP
                \else% NO YEAR STEP REQUIRED
                \fi
            \stepcounter{month}%
            \else% NOT 31
            \ifnum \value{day} = 30% NOT 31, 30?
                \ifnum \value{month} = 4%
                    \stepcounter{month}%
                    \else
                    \ifnum \value{month} = 6%
                        \stepcounter{month}%
                        \else
                        \ifnum \value{month} = 9%
                            \stepcounter{month}%
                            \else
                            \ifnum \value{month} = 11%
                                \stepcounter{month}%
                                \else
                                \fi
                            \fi
                        \fi
                    \fi
                \else% NOT 30
                \ifnum \value{month} = 2% IS IT FEB?
                    \pgfmathparse{int(ceil(mod(\theyear,4)))}%
                    \ifnum \pgfmathresult = 0% LEAP YEAR?
                        \ifnum \value{day} = 29%
                            \stepcounter{month}%
                            \else
                            \fi
                        \else% feb, NOT LEAP YEAR
                            \ifnum \value{day} = 28%
                                \stepcounter{month}%
                                \else
                                \fi
                        \fi
                    \else% NOT FEB AND/OR DAY TOO LOW
                    \fi
                \fi
            \fi
        \stepcounter{day}% DAY GETS STEPED NO MATTER WHAT
        \setcounter{mrow}{0}%
        &%
        }
    \newcommand*{\dddate}{% CALLS DATE, DOESN'T INCREMENT, FOR USE ON TOP PART OF PAGEBROKEN DAY
        \small%
        \ifbool{rcc}% DATE TEXT COLOR
            {\color{oddRowTextColor}}%
            {\color{evenRowTextColor}}%
        \ifnumcomp{\value{mrow}}{>}{2}%
            {% DATE FORM
                \ifnumcomp{\value{mrow}}{>}{4}% 
                    {\multirow{-\value{mrow}}{*}}%
                    {\multirow{-\value{mrow}}{*}}%
                {\rotatebox{90}{% for m column
                    \ifnumcomp{\value{day}}{<}{10}% IF SINGLE DIGIT DAY
                        {0\theday.}%
                        {\theday.}%
                    \ifnumcomp{\value{month}}{<}{10}% IF SINGLE DIGIT MONTH
                        {0\themonth.}%
                        {\themonth.}%
                    \ifnumcomp{\value{mrow}}{>}{4}% ROOM FOR YEAR?
                        {\StrRight{\theyear}{2}}%
                        {}%
                }}%
            }%
            {}%
        \setcounter{mrow}{0}%
        &%
        }
    \newcommand*{\QQ}[8][&]{%
        \ifblank{#8}%
            {\stepcounter{row}\stepcounter{mrow}}%
            {% REMARKS NOT BLANK
                \setbox1=\hbox{\noindent#8}% fixme
                \pgfmathparse{int(ceil(divide(\wd1,312.4)))}%
                \ifstrequal{#1}{&}%
                    {\addtocounter{row}{\pgfmathresult}\addtocounter{mrow}{\pgfmathresult}}%
                    {\addtocounter{row}{\pgfmathresult}\stepcounter{mrow}}%
            }%
        \ifblank{#3}{}{\addtostream{data}{\theyear-%
            \ifnumcomp{\value{month}}{<}{10}{0\themonth-}{\themonth-}\ifnumcomp{\value{day}}{<}{10}{0\theday}{\theday} #2, #3}}% 
        \ifbool{rc}%
            {\rowstyle{\color{evenRowTextColor}}\global\boolfalse{rc}}%
            {\rowstyle{\color{oddRowTextColor}}\global\booltrue{rc}}%
        \ifbool{rcc}%
            {\cellcolor{oddRowColor}}%
            {\cellcolor{evenRowColor}}%
        #1%  date
        #2&% time
        #3&% blood glucose
        #4&% insulin
        #5&% carbohydrates
        #6&% protein
        #7&% fat
        #8%  remarks
        \\%
        }
    \newcommand*{\QQQ}[8][]{%
        \ifnumgreater{\value{row}}{\myc}%% IS LAST ROW? FIXME, MAXROW??/
            {% LAST ROW- RESET COUNTER, UNLESS EXPLICITLY LAST ROW OF RESP. DATE, I.E., HAS DATE CALL, WILL NOT INCREMENT DAY
                \setcounter{row}{0}%
                \ifblank{#1}%
                    {\QQ[\dddate]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}\pagebreak}% PAGEBROKEN DAY
                    {\QQ[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}\pagebreak}%
            }%
            {% NOT LAST ROW OR SELF-CALLED  
                \ifblank{#1}%
                    {\QQ{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}%
                    {\QQ[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}%
            }%
        }%
    % APPLYING TEXT COLOR FROM CELL TO CELL WITHIN ROW
    \makeatletter

    \newcommand*{\@rowstyle}{}

    \newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{% sets the style of the next row
    \gdef\@rowstyle{#1}%
    \@rowstyle\ignorespaces%
    }

    \newcolumntype{=}{% resets the row style
    >{\gdef\@rowstyle{}}%
    }

    \newcolumntype{+}{% adds the current row style to the next column
    >{\@rowstyle}%
    }

    \makeatother
%
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \fontfamily{pag}\selectfont
    \footnotesize
    \def\myc{75}% #maxrows, determined exp.
    \rowcolors{2}{oddRowColor}{evenRowColor}
\setcounter{year}{2018}
\setcounter{month}{3}
\setcounter{day}{31}
\begin{longtable}{=l +l| +l +l +l +l +l | +m{11cm}}\hline
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\QQQ[\ddate]{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\QQQ[\ddate]{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\QQQ[\ddate]{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\QQQ[\ddate]{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\QQQ[\ddate]{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\QQQ[\ddate]{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\QQQ[\ddate]{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\QQQ[\ddate]{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\QQQ[\ddate]{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \QQQ{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\QQQ[\ddate]{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I upvote your hard and long well work.

Answer (score 1):

If using `\multirow` you should always use `\\*` on the spanned rows to stop a break appearing in the span.

[image]

I fixed a few unrelated things in the document preamble

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,longtable,multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.25cm, right=1.25cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\selectcolormodel{gray}\rowcolors{2}{white}{yellow}
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{l l| l l l l l | p{11cm}}

\rowcolor{white}\caption{title}\\
%
\rowcolor{white}\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Time} & BG & Ins. & CHO & Pro & Fat & Remarks \\ \hline\endfirsthead
%
\rowcolor{white}\caption{\emph{cont.}}\\ 
\rowcolor{white}\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Time} & BG & Ins. & CHO & Pro & Fat & Remarks \\ \hline\endhead
\hline\endfoot
%%% Copy-paste as many date as necessary to see issue
    \cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{yellow}\rotatebox{90}{08.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{white}\rotatebox{90}{09.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
    \cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{yellow}\rotatebox{90}{08.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{white}\rotatebox{90}{09.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
    \cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{yellow}\rotatebox{90}{08.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{white}\rotatebox{90}{09.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
    \cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{yellow}\rotatebox{90}{08.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{white}\rotatebox{90}{09.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
    \cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{yellow}\rotatebox{90}{08.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{white}\rotatebox{90}{09.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
    \cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{yellow}\rotatebox{90}{08.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{white}\rotatebox{90}{09.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
    \cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{yellow}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{yellow}\rotatebox{90}{08.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*\cellcolor{white}&
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
\multirow{-11}{*}{\cellcolor{white}\rotatebox{90}{09.03.18}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
%%% 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```